# Selenium automation with InternetExplorer driver throwing Javascript error

Tags: javascript, selenium, internet-explorer

I am trying to automate Salesforce website and the following codes works perfectly well when I am running it on Chrome driver. When I switch to Internet Explorer driver, I am encountering a "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: JavaScript error". I have tried the following fixes for IE11 issues:
1. Enabled protection mode wherever necessary
2. Enabled Javascript
3. Enabled Zoom option.
4. Used 32bit driver instead of 64bit.

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class scenario1 {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\IEDriverServer.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        /****Opening web page****/
        driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/");

        /****Enter credentials to login****/
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("*******");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).submit();

        /*********Chatter tab ********/

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 500);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Chatter_Tab")));


        driver.findElement(By.id("Chatter_Tab")).submit();
    }
    }
```

Comment: which line you are getting the error try running it in debug mode

Comment: It's throwing an error on " wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Chatter_Tab")));"

Comment: can you try increase the waiting time  to see if the element is visible at that time, it will through exception if the `Chatter_Tab` is not visible after login within 500 sec

Comment: use above 2.28 v of selenium if you are using below there is a known issue

Comment: Thanks, I tried increasing it to 3000 and 30000 as well but it still shows "Javascript error" ... Let me also try the version

Comment: I am using a 3.4 version selenium... I don't know what to do